# Explicit Wait in helper class to be used when needed by test cases

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am trying to create a helper class that holds different waits for Selenium WebDriver. This is to give the user more flexibility when creating test cases. I am having some issues with the helper class for Explicit waits.

**Test Case**

```
[Test]
[TestCase(Browser.Chrome)]
public void ValidateExpicitWait(Browser browser)
{
    Driver = StaticWebDriverFactory.GetLocalWebDriver(browser);
    Driver.Url = "https://example.com/";
    WaitsHelper.SetExplicitWait(Driver, ElementIdentifierType.LinkText, "More information...", 10);

    var title = Driver.Title;
    Assert.AreEqual(true, title.Contains("Example Domain"), $"Expected title does not match actual: {title}", title);
}
```

**Explicit Wait Class**

```
public static void SetExplicitWait(IWebDriver driver, ElementIdentifierType identifierType, string identifer, int timeout = 10)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
    IWebElement element = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.identifierType(identifer));
    });

}
```

It has a issue with `identifierType` from `d.FindElement(By.identifierType(identifier));`

**Error**

> 'By' does not contain a definition for 'identifierType

Comment: The error message is quite clear. What is `ElementIdentifierType`?

Comment: `ElementIdentifierType` is a `enum` containing the different identifiers `Id, Name, ClassName, etc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`By` class can't convert an `Enum` to static method, it doesn't have `identifierType` method. You can send `By` object instead

```
public static void SetExplicitWait(IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeout = 10)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
    IWebElement element = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(by);
    });
}

WaitsHelper.SetExplicitWait(Driver, By.LinkText("More information..."), 10);
```